# bind held key without blocking typing

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xbindkeys, sxhkd

I have a foot pedal that I would like to toggle a file's contents when pressed and released.
I have got the foot pedal acting like a normal key with a keycode and disabled it from repeating with `xset -r <keycode>`.
But when I bind it to a command with sxhkd/xbindkeys they block me from typing while it is pressed. I need to be able to type while it is pressed.

sxhkd:

```
F25
    echo dictate > ~/mode
@F25
    echo command > ~/mode
```